# Bound on the number of unlabeled tree on n vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, trees

By the Cayley's Theorem, the number of labeled tree on n vertices is at most n^{n-2}. On the other hand, what is the bound on the number of unlabeled tree on n vertices?

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A000055.

Comment: It is at most $n4^n$. One way to do this is to count unlabeled rooted trees; these can be uniquely encoded using balanced parantheses and orderings. If the subtrees at the children of the root have encodings $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_k$ with $e_1 \leq e_2 \leq \ldots \leq e_k$, then the encoding for the tree is $((e_1)(e_2) \ldots (e_k))$.